# Horror short film with a woman pursued by the ghosts who exhort her to remove her clothing

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I remember watching this on YouTube as a short film (maybe 30 minutes) somewhere in 2019-2020. It was a short horror film where the main character, a young woman, was about to head out for a night clubbing, but she kept getting eerie text messages implying that someone was in her apartment with her.

There were multiple shots involving the flash of a cigarette lighter showing someone else in her apartment, which I think was implied to be a young man of Indian or Asian descent after he showed up at her door with a delivery.

The eventual climax involved a female, maybe badly burned, figure showing up in her apartment, paired with shots of piles of her clothing. By the end, it's revealed that

> the things stalking her are the ghosts of sweatshop workers who died because she wanted cheap clothing. The film ended with a PSA about sweatshops and how we're passively enabling them.

The short film was advertised in a somewhat scandalous manner indicating that the goal of the ghosts was for her to take off her clothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*TAKE OFF YOUR CLOTHES*, a 2019 short film by the Grim crew, directed by Felix Charin.

It ends:

[image: "Dedicated to the people around the world, living and dying horribly so that we can have cheap clothes"]

Other than that, your recollection matches pretty well and I can't really add anything more to it than the [Vimeo link to the short](https://vimeo.com/373427729).

---

Found with the Google query `short film horror take off clothing`, after several variations of `short film horror psa asia sweatshops "fast fashion"` did not yield anything relevant.

Comment: That is exactly it. Thank you.